# Select items from distinct categories, including articles with no category

Tags: mysql, sql

This seems like it would be pretty simple to do. I have a table of articles that has the following fields relevant to this question:

```
id - INTEGER(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
category_id - INTEGER(11) DEFAULT(-1)
```

When an article has a category, its ID goes in the category_id field. When it has no category, the column's value is -1.

What I want to do is to select three random articles of distinct categories from this articles table. This alone is pretty simple to do:

```
SELECT id FROM articles GROUP BY category_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;
```

However, I don't want to group articles with no category into one single category, like the previous query would do. That is, I want to treat each article with a category_id of -1 as being in a separate category. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union` to create a derived table that contains

1. 1 article id per non -1 category
2. All article ids for -1 category

And then select 3 random ids from that table

```
select id from (
    select id from articles
    where category_id <> -1
    group by category_id
    union all
    select id from articles
    where category_id = -1
) t order by rand() limit 3;
```

As pointed out in the comments, the query above will likely return the same article id per category id. If that's an issue you can try the query below but it might run slowly since it's ordering the tables by rand() twice.

```
select id from (
    select id from (
        select id from articles
        where category_id <> -1
        order by rand()
    ) t 
    group by category_id
    union all
    select id from articles
    where category_id = -1
) t order by rand() limit 3;
```

Comment: The subquery that groups by category may not be very random. The selection is arbitrary, but it's likely to be consistent from one query to the next if the table hasn't changed.

Comment: @Barmar that's true. i considered making the query truly random but decided against it because it seems this query is already expensive as it is.